# Include rowid in generated jOOQ Record

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jooq

I'm using jOOQ with Oracle DB and need to get the rowid of a Record.

Is it possible to include the rowid in the generated jOOq Records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What's available in jOOQ 3.12

jOOQ 3.12 introduced [`Table.rowid()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Table.html#rowid()) with [#7885](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7885), and as such, the necessary infrastructure to do what you want to do. However, right now (as of jOOQ 3.12), there's no way to indicate to the code generator or to `UpdatableRecord` in general that there exists such an artificial `ROWID` column. Pending feature requests include:

- [#6168](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6168) Add Setting to perform UpdatableRecord actions using Table.rowid() instead of the primary key
- [#8388](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8388) Add code generation option to make all records UpdatableRecords

#### Workarounds

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could write views that represent your tables on a 1:1 basis, adding the `ROWID` column to each row. Using [`syntheticPrimaryKeys`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-synthetic-primary-keys/) and other code generation options, you could make those views look like your base tables again, to the code generator.

You could also extend the classes in `jOOQ-meta` to produce a synthetic `ROWID` column on each generated record, and if desired, use `overridePrimaryKeys` to tell the code generator that the `ROWID` is the primary key, not the actual primary key, if this is what you want. Of course, you'd have to make sure you'll never write to that column...

Other than that, you can fetch the [`Table.rowid()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Table.html#rowid()) manually in all manually constructed queries. They will be separate from your `UpdatableRecord` instances, though. You could use `ResultQuery.fetchMap()` methods to produce a mapping between rowids and records.

Comment: Thank you I will try the second workaround because there are too many tables (~1500) where I'm using Records to create views.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: I've thought of another workaround where you'd be extending the `jOOQ-meta` classes to add the `ROWID` information to each generated record, see above.

Comment: Ah yes I see. Will have to try that. Thank you